# Unable to fix a Access Violation reading location error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, access-violation

So, I've looked around for an answer for a while, trying to solve this error. I think I know what the problem is, but I still can't find where or how it's happening exactly.

The error is that I'm getting a Access Violation at the location 0xcccccccc. My searching has lead me to that the problem is that I'm trying to delete a pointer that either doesn't exist, which I don't believe, or that I'm deleting a temporary variable. The problem is that I can't figure out which it is. I'm sure that once it's pointed out I'll feel stupid, but I REALLY can't seem to see this.

Pertinent Code down the callstack from the top.

```
// Minimum Polynomial Function
matrix matrix::MIN_POLY()
{
  // Get stuff ready to find the Minimal Polynomial of the matrix
  // Get our I matrix in.

  col[0] = MatrixPow( *this, 0); // Goes in here <-

// ... Rest of the function ...

}



// Matrix Power Function
matrix matrix::MatrixPow(matrix& A, int pow)
{
  // Create an identity matrix should the pow == 0
  matrix ret(A.size[0], A.size[1]);

  for(int i = 0; i < ret.size[0]; ++i)
  {
    ret.data[i][i] = 1;
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < pow; ++i)
  {
    // multiply it by the number of times given, and 0 returns I
    ret = MatrixMult(ret, A);
  }

  // Ret.data exists here still and is ready to be moved and deleted.
  return ret; // Seems to call Copy around here for some reason. <------
}



// Copy constructor
matrix::matrix(const matrix& other)
{
  // Ret.data is gone by here for some reason.
  if(data)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < size[0]; ++i)
    {
      delete[] data[i]; // Error happens in one of these deletes <-----
    }
  delete[] data;
  }
// Rest doesn't matter as it stops above
}
```

And the matrix.h since it was asked for.

```
#include <complex>

class matrix
{
private:
  std::complex<float> **data; // [row][column]
  int size[2]; // 0 is rows/ 1 is columns

public:
  // Default Constructor 
  matrix();
  // Default Destructor
  ~matrix();
  // Default Copy
  matrix(const matrix& other);
  // Premade matrix constructor
  matrix(int row, int col, std::complex<float>** mat);
  // Assignment operator to get stuff done
  matrix& operator=(const matrix& other);
  // Set function for the matrix
  void Set(int row, int col, std::complex<float> dat);
  // Get function for the matrix, inline for ease.
  std::complex<float> Get(int row, int col)
  {return data[row][col];}
  // Get function for the number of rows
  int GetRows()
  {return size[0];}
  // Get function for the number of columns
  int GetCol()
  {return size[1];}
  // Scalar Multiplication
  void ScalarMult(std::complex<float> scalar);
  // Matrix Multiplication
  matrix MatrixMult(const matrix& A, const matrix& B);
  // Matrix Power series
  matrix MatrixPow(matrix& A, int pow);
  // Matrix addition
  matrix MatrixAdd(const matrix& lhs, const matrix& rhs);
  // Row op addition
  void RowOp(int row1, int row2, std::complex<float> val1, std::complex<float> val2);
  // Row op Swap
  void RowSwap(int row1, int row2);
  // RREF function
  void RREF();
  // minimal Polynomial
  matrix MIN_POLY();
};
```

Comment: This is going to be tough for us to debug with (a) so much code, and (b) a missing `matrix.h`. Any chance you can reduce this to a smaller example that also fails?

Comment: in `matrix` _copy_ constructor, you delete `data` which has not been initialized. The delete could make sense in an assignment operator, but not here. Just get rid of that whole `if` block.

Comment: Added the matrix.h and cleaned up some of the unneeded code. Also, the reason it's not been made in the copy is because I wanted to clean up any array that's already there. Would that really cause a problem?

Comment: you won't have an array already there, the copy constructor creates a new instance.

Comment: Weird, didn't think about it like that. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You define copy constructor:

```
matrix::matrix(const matrix& other)
```

Do not initialize members:

```
matrix::matrix(const matrix& other)
{
    //body...
}
```

And then perform such check:

```
if(data)
```

Which by all means cannot be false - all pointers all initialized to compiler-specific sentinel value to indicate uninitialized state and help detect bugs like this. This usually applies to debug builds, unless you enable this also in release builds.

Solution:

**1.** Initialize `data`:

```
matrix::matrix(const matrix& other)
: data(NULL)
{
    //body...
}
```

**2.** Do not perform this unnecessary check:

```
matrix::matrix(const matrix& other)
: data(NULL)
{
  // copy size
  size[0] = other.size[0];
  size[1] = other.size[1];

  // Make the numbers match
  data = new std::complex<float>*[size[0]];
  for(int i = 0; i < size[0]; ++i)
  {
    data[i] = new std::complex<float>[size[1]];
    for(int j = 0; j < size[1]; ++j)
    {
      data[i][j] = other.data[i][j];
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Really? It doesn't feel right that way... but... when pointed out it sound right.  It still doesn't feel right though...

Comment: It is **very** right. Constructor is called for uninitialized object, so unless you manually provide valid initial state, you cannot expect members to have certain values (expect from those default-constructed, with valid default constructors defined).

Comment: Yeah, I feel that now, I feel silly for thinking that. I guess it slipped that it was a constructor from copy rather than construct then copy. Thank you, I hope to never make this mistake again.